# Suppose A and B are disjoint, while B and C are disjoint as well.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I am currently trying to understand this example in the textbook and it's not really making any sense to me.

Lets say A and B are disjoint, while B and C are disjoint as well.

According to the textbook, we have the following:

$\Pr((A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)) = \Pr(A \cap C)$

**Here is what I think about the above sentence (correct me if I am wrong):**

Is this following statement true because $\Pr(A \cap B) = \emptyset$ and that the empty set union any set is just the set itself or is there something much more that I am missing here?

Rather than saying the empty set, is it actually more appropriate to say $\Pr(A \cap B) = 0$? Is it alright to say empty set or $0$?

Comment: You should try to use the LaTeX markup for mathematics.

Comment: "Pr(A intersection B) = empty set" is an incorrect statement, since Pr(A intersection B) must be a number while the empty set is a set. You can say that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and thus $\text{Pr}(A \cap B) = 0$.

Comment: Ahh..I see, Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say that $A \cap B = \varnothing$ and by definition $Pr(\varnothing) = 0$ (probability of an event in the empty set occurring is zero). However, this reasoning makes use of the fact that $A \cap B$ and $A \cap C$ are disjoint, otherwise you cannot split probability of their union into the sum of probabilities.

However, the statement is still true even when $B,C$ are not disjoint, because $A \cap B = \varnothing$ gives $A \cap B \cup A \cap C = \varnothing \cup A \cap C = A \cap C$.